# Android: "Calling thread must be a prepared Looper thread" error when I use AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading

I've created a AsyncTask to retrieve a GPS position with a 20-meter accuracy.
I would like to execute a while do cycle until accuracy is accetable.

The problem is that I got an exception when I request an update of position.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Calling thread must be a prepared Looper thread.
```

This is the piece of code that goes in error

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return null;
            }
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(100);
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            while (mLastLocation == null || (mLastLocation.getAccuracy()>Float.parseFloat("20.0") && mLastLocation.hasAccuracy())){
                try {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,activity);
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                } catch (SecurityException secex) {

                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You are doing something UI related in your doInBackgroud()

Comment: add `Looper.perpare()` at first in `doInBackgroud()`. I'm not sure, but have a try.

Comment: post the complete log output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had troubles with this a full work day. I have the FusedLocationApi running in background within a Service.

What I a did -I read it somewhere else- is add Looper.getMainLooper() as the last parameter of `requestLocationUpdates()`.

So, instead of this

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,activity);
```

You'll have

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

If your read the whole [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) page, you will see that the method will do different thing depending on the parameters.

Comment: BE CAREFUL with this!  All of the code in your callback will be ran on the mainUI thread.  If it's intensive code you can make your application janky.

Comment: I tried different methods to solve that issue. I even set its own looper and handlers but didn't work. I stop using that method to get location updates. I am using the FusedLocationClient to do it, it does not require this parameter.

Comment: See my new answer.  It should avoid the MainThread issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068298/42994

Comment: You are using Guava.. Particularly I stick to the framework, even if Guava was developed by google.

Comment: Yeah your solution didn't quite fit my use case.  I needed a location once in a background fetch method and I didn't want to keep the gps on.  Though what you have is probably the more common use case for location.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Looper.prepare() or runOnUiThread()` function to make changes in UI when running in doInBackground or make changes in methods other than doInBackground

Example :

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                progressBar.setTitle("Downloading Files...");
                progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setMax(100);
                progressBar.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Looper.prepare() seems works! I don't understand why needed it because I do not make changes in UI. (googleapiclient is part of UI?)

Comment: runOnUiThread() works on Runnable, the AsyncTask is not accepted as parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: If Looper.prepare() works then you are executing multiple runnables at the same time. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

I used [SettableFuture](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) from guava so that I wouldn't run unnecessary code on the main looper when the call returned. (this could be a problem if your callback kicks off some heavy work load and can lead to UI jank.)

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      SettableFuture<Location> future = SettableFuture.create();
       Log.w(TAG, "before fused call isMainLooper= %b", Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread());
      // future.set runs on the main thread.  
      //future.get stays on the background thread.
      mFusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
          client,
          LOCATION_REQUEST,
          location1 -> {
             future.set(location1);
      Log.w(TAG, "callback: isMainLooper= %b", Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread());

          }
          Looper.getMainLooper());

      location = future.get(10, SECONDS);
      Log.w(TAG, "after fused call isMainLooper= %b", Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread());
```

Log output

```
W TAG: before fused call isMainLooper = false
W TAG: callback: isMainLooper = true
W TAG: after fused call isMainLooper = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem while getting locations in background. When I found the out the exception I added Looper.getMainLooper.. then I decided to read again the documentation and I completely change the way how I get location in background; the difference is using the `FusedLocationProviderClient` and callbacks like this.

First define your provider client.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
```

Define location callbacks, make sure you use `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback`

```
/**
 * Fuse location api callback
 */
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

            mLastLocation = location;                

            //Send to your server or update your UI

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {

        super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
        //Send to your server or update your UI

    }
};
```

Define a method to request location updates

```
public void startLocationUpdates() {

    boolean hasLocationPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    if (!hasLocationPermission) {
        gettingLocationUpdates = false;
        return;
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, /*Looper*/ null);

    com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<Location> task = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();

    task.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {

        mLastLocation = task1.getResult();

        gettingLocationUpdates = true;

    });
}
```

Initialize it in onCreate of your service and start requesting updates

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    startLocationUpdates();
}
```

Don't forget to remove the locations updates, or it will never stop

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
     mFusedLocationClient.flushLocations();                         
   mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
```

Give it a try and let me know.